# Create multiple Objects without multiple declarations

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a routine `Init_buffer` (which create a new buffer to new a new client). So far I only discovered this way (in pseudo-code):

```
//Globally
BufferClass buffer1('some_random_size');
BufferClass buffer2('some_random_size');
BufferClass buffer3('some_random_size');
(...)
//Binary data (chunck) from Nodejs Server
void buffering_mem(char* chunk, int size_chunk, int close_file,
                   int client, int total_size) {
  if(client == 0) {
    buffer1.write(chunk,size_chunk);
  }
  else if(client == 1) {
    buffer2.write(chunk, size_chunk);
  }
  (...)
}
```

Now I want to do the whole process without the repetition of code. Any ideas?

Comment: use an array of `BufferClass`?

Comment: Create an object and push it into a `std::vector`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Piters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read up on how to use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Something a bit like this:

```
std::vector<BufferClass> buffers(3, BufferClass(1024));

void buffering_mem(char* chunk, int size_chunk, int close_file
    , int client, int total_size)
{
    if(client >= buffers.size())
        throw std::range_error("out of range client: " + std::to_string(client));

    buffers[client].write(chunk, size_chunk);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference and the tip.